# Generate N*N documents

Tags: java, multithreading, document

I have a problem. My Spring boot project receives a JSON with options and a XML that I call *ORIGINAL XML*.

Each option comes with tags that have to be modified over the original XML.

Lest use this JSON:

`Option 1 = N values
 Option 2 = M values
 Option 3 = K values
 .....
 Option X = R values`

each option must create X variations based on values I have. For instance:
For the ORIGINAL XML I have to create N variations for option 1, option 2 must create M variations of documents from option 1, option 3 must create K variations of documents from options 2, and so on.

It should give variations of NxMxKxR **ORIGINAL XML**.

following my algorithm, i got next error:

> 2018-12-04 11:37:55.125  WARN 7296 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=49s823ms348µs491ns)

Mi variations are generated in this way:

[Create documents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdEvn.png)

each TareaRastrojo  is an Object which behaves like this:

[Task scenario maker - Threads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwloN.png)

the threads context switching works ok,where i can see messages with no order.

problem is that CPU goes at 100% and does not end its task with 500 scenario left to create.

Notice that im testing with creation of 5^5 documents = 3125 and it works good but it fails with 5^6 = 15625 in range 11000 to 12000.

some thoughts about why it fails in that range?

[CPU al 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFko1.png)

Comment: Aquí solo hablamos inglés.  Yo recomiendo http://es.stackoverflow.com

Comment: You're running out of threads, which is rather like running out of memory: We often consider it an inexhaustible resource, but there actually is some limit. The usual recourse in Spring is a [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html).